# select m.code ms.translation ms.lastupdatedby ms.lastupdateddate from message m message-translation ms where ms.message

Tags: jpa

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name=Message.QUERY_GET_LEC_MESSAGE, query="SELECT m.message_id, m.code ,ms.translation , m.lastupdated_by , m.lastupdated_date FROM Message ms JOIN MessageTranslation m ON ms.message_id=m.message_id")})
```

The above query I am getting an error while deploying to JBOSS. Please say me what would be the right way for the above-NAMED Query.